# Check if an HTML element is an HTML media element

Tags: javascript, html, media

I'm building a helper function to insert elements into the DOM. Here's what I have so far:

```
function insertElem(numberOfElems, elemTag, elemId, elemClass, parentSelector){
/*
* numberOfElements:-    Pass in a plain whole integer.
* elemId:-              Pass in a name for the element id (inside "" or ''),
                        an integer is appended to the id name by the for loop.               
* elemTag:-             Pass in the element tag type (inside "" or '').                   
* parentSelector:-      Pass in the identifier of the parent element (inside "" or '')
                        *querySelector prefixes:    # = id
                                                    . = class
                                                    none = tag               
*/      
  if (numberOfElems > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfElems; i++) {
      var elem = this[elemId + i];
      elem = document.createElement(elemTag);
      elem.id = elemId + '_' + i;
      elem.className = elemClass;
      parentEl = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
      parentEl.appendChild(elem);
    }
  } else {
    var elem = this[elemId];
    elem = document.createElement(elemTag);
    elem.id = elemId;
    elem.className = elemClass;
    parentEl = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
    parentEl.appendChild(elem);
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to check if "elem" is an HTML media element so that I can add an argument ("elemSrc") to my function.

Pseudo code:

```
if (elem is an html media element) {
   elem.src = media url;
}
```

Comment: Why not just have an object of properties to set and loop over it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to see if it is an [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test1') instanceof HTMLMediaElement)
console.log(document.getElementById('test2') instanceof HTMLMediaElement)
```

```html
<video id="test1"></video>
<div id="test2"></video>
```

Comment: Cheers Dave, that sounds like it will do the trick. I will try that out when I get chance & give feedback when I have done so! Ta!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Dave's answer above, `HTMLMediaElement` is the base class for `HTMLAudioElement` and `HTMLVideoElement` so if you want to check for a specific type of media, you can also do that using the `instanceof` the respective mentioned types.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip Dave, this does what I want for now:-

```
function insertElem(numberOfElems, elemTag, elemId, elemClass, parentSelector, elemSrc){
    /*
    * numberOfElements:-    Pass in a whole integer.
    * elemTag:-             Pass in the element tag type (inside "" or '').              
    * elemId:-              Pass in a name for the element id (inside "" or ''),
                            an integer is appended to the id name by the for loop.
    * elemClass:-           Pass in a name for element class (inside "" or '').
    * parentSelector:-      Pass in the identifier of the parent element (inside "" or '')
                            * querySelector prefixes:    # = id
                                                         . = class
                                                         none = tag 
    *elemSrc:-              Pass in the source media url (inside "" or ''). 
    */      
      if (numberOfElems > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfElems; i++) {
          var elem = this[elemId + i];
          elem = document.createElement(elemTag);
          elem.id = elemId + '_' + i;
             if (elemClass) {
                elem.className = elemClass;
             }
          parentEl = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
          parentEl.appendChild(elem);
            if(elem instanceof HTMLMediaElement) {
                elem.src = elemSrc;
            }
        }
      } else {
        var elem = this[elemId];
        elem = document.createElement(elemTag);
        elem.id = elemId;
            if (elemClass) {
                elem.className = elemClass;
            }
        parentEl = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
        parentEl.appendChild(elem);
           if(elem instanceof HTMLMediaElement) {
                elem.src = elemSrc;
          }
      }
    }
```